# Replace a cell value after doing a formula from elsewhere in the document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a budget spreadsheet with a few accounts we need to get paid off. I have a dropdown menu with all the accounts and an "amount paid" cell where we would type the amount in.   I would love the amount in the column to subtract from the amount in the paid amount cell and update the total.

This would be a lot easier to show. I've created a link with the spreadsheet in mind.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OUC5uyrc6l9SSGgJ9Akk8H7eSohu2iBRytlgKxI60lg/edit?usp=sharing

Basically, I want the value in B6 to be subtracted from the corresponding value in column F.
My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to get the new value to find the right row in column F

This is probably rudimentary and I'm probably missing something simple.

```
function newtotal() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Budget");
  var ssc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Calculations");
  var values = ssc.getRange('D1');
  var newtotal = values.getValue(); 

  Logger.log(newtotal)

}
```

Comment: Your missing what you have done to try to provide the solution yourself.  Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: Please put it into your question.

Comment: I've tried to write a simple code for what I'm looking to do, but I fear that I'm just not as adept as I should be yet. I don't know how to call the correct row to insert the new value in the column. I've updated the question with some code I've tried to start, it logs the correct value.

Comment: Your script doesn't even attempt to accomplish what  your  asking for.  Keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function funcOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Budget');
  var rg=sh.getRange(3,5,sh.getLastRow()-3,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var justPaid=sh.getRange(6,1).getValue();
  var amount=sh.getRange(6,2).getValue();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]==justPaid) {
      sh.getRange(i+3,6).setValue(sh.getRange(i+3,6).getValue()-amount);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That script works flawlessly. I understand the variables and what they are accomplishing. I don't however understand what I'm assuming is the meat of the code. the "for" line.   I somewhat understand everything after "if"

Comment: [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)  [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)